# Guice provision errors on AppEngine with GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, guice, gwt-platform

We sporadically receive errors in our GWT/GAE application related to Guice. Stack trace is below.

Most of the time, it lasts only a couple of minutes and for only a few requests. The latest was this morning when it happened for almost an hour for over 20 requests.

Each error seems to be in the same place: HttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.getSession.

```
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (23283a43283f7eb3) started at 2012/01/27 14:47:06.787 UTC and was still executing at 2012/01/27 14:48:06.670 UTC.
  at com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule.provideHttpSession(InternalServletModule.java:103)
  while locating javax.servlet.http.HttpSession

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:977)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.guice.HttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.getSession(HttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.java:54)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractHttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:422)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (23283a43283f7eb3) started at 2012/01/27 14:47:06.787 UTC and was still executing at 2012/01/27 14:48:06.670 UTC.
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:258)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:91)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$CumulativeAggregateFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:144)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:72)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:33)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:31)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.newHttpSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:413)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getSession(Request.java:1242)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getSession(Request.java:1214)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule.provideHttpSession(InternalServletModule.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:968)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1014)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:964)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.guice.HttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.getSession(HttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.java:54)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractHttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpSessionSecurityCookieFilter.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a request that lasts more than 30 seconds, this is why you get the exception. The only way to fix that is to reduce the time to execute your request.

Comment: Agreed but the stack trace implies that it's Guice that's taking too long to get whatever dependencies it needs. In this case, it looks like it can't get hold of the HTTP session.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with Guice, see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/DeadlineExceededException.html